# How to combine simplequerystring with bool/must

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have this ElasticSearch query for ES version 7:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "simple_query_string": {
    "query": "*"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "organization_id": "fred"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "assigned_user_id": "24584080"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "updated": "desc"
  },
  "terminate_after": 50,
}
```

but ES gives me back this error:

> reason: Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [simple_query_string]

my goal is to be able to use a query-string for multiple fields, and also use term/match with bool/must.  Should I abandon the query string and just use `bool.must[{match:"my query"}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use bool to combine multiple queries in this way. The must clause will work as logical AND, and will make sure all the conditions are matched.**

**You need to include the simple_query_string inside the query section**

Adding Working example with sample docs, and search query.

**Index Sample Data**

```
{
  "organization_id": 1,
  "assigned_user_id": 2,
  "title": "welcome"
}{
  "organization_id": 2,
  "assigned_user_id": 21,
  "title": "hello"
}{
  "organization_id": 3,
  "assigned_user_id": 22,
  "title": "hello welocome"
}
```

**Search Query :**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields" : ["title"],
            "query" : "welcome"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "organization_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "assigned_user_id": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 3.0925694,
            "_source": {
                "organization_id": 1,
                "assigned_user_id": 2,
                "title": "welcome"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: @rakim did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: @rakim any luck with this?

Comment: @rakim can you please reply to my above questions ?